# How can I change my skin on the fly?

Tags: php, mediawiki

Using PHP and mainly spoons...

Here's what determines my skins now:

```
if ( preg_match("/(mobile|webos|opera mini)/i",$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])
) {
    $wgDefaultSkin = 'wptouch';
} else {
    $wgDefaultSkin = 'vector';
}
```

If it's mobile it gets a mobile skin, if not it gets the standard skin.  This is declared in the LocalSettings.php (configuration) file, so it seems like a jQuery solution wouldn't work, but I'm open to suggestions.

I feel like the best solution here would be a button or link that fires off a PHP function that refreshes the page and somehow changes that variables definition.

Comment: My usual approach: Add a corresponding class with PHP to the `body` and target them with CSS.

Comment: How do you mean?  Like using CSS media queries?  I need to be able to declare different skins with completely different HTML.

Comment: Oh, so your html is different? Then yeah, I guess you'd have to refresh the page then, (or AJAX). Something like `$skin = $_POST['skin'] ?: 'desktop'` for example and then print accordingly.

Comment: What's wrong with the PHP? And yes, you could amend it with a skin cookie that allows the user to overwrite the UA name preset.

Answer (score 1):

In theory, one solution is to use the MobileFrontend extension, which has such a detector by itself, and replace the Minerva skin it ships with yours.